# How to handle mousedown event on chart part?

Tags: highcharts

I'm looking a way to handle any mouse down event within an highchart/highstock graph. Currently I'm using the custom-events plugin but it doesn't offer this event on the chart object.

What will be the proper way to handle this event on the chart part?

Thanks,

Manu

Comment: check this [plugin](https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events)

Comment: I tried this plugin but it doesn't cover the chart area unfortunately. I end up doing as @d_paul mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `onmousedown` event attribute in container div. You could also use jQuery events.

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/5Lu4at1s/ - with event attribute
http://jsfiddle.net/bLtqp24d/ - using jQuery mousedown event

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but now I'm facing the issue that I get events for the whole container whereas I just want the event on the chart area. How do I achieve this without looking at the internal of highcharts layout?

Comment: You can for example overwrite chart.container.onmousedown event. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t2g1tk2L/.

Comment: I end up adding the the handlers on the container and use Highcharts `isInsidePlot` to figure out if the mouse events are within the chart.